# How to set up a web server to serve jsp files in Fedora 15?

Tags: web-server, tomcat6, jsp

I have installed Fedora 15 on my system. Installed Web server using the command

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Web Server"
```

Have it running successfully at port 80. The files are put in "/var/www/html". It is supporting html and php. i would like to have support for jsp also. I have googled a lot for a good tutorial on setting up the server ready for serving jsp files. But failed to find a good tutorial.
Found this by searching here [JSP / Tomcat / Apache setup overview on Fedora Core](https://serverfault.com/questions/112132/jsp-tomcat-apache-setup-overview-on-fedora-core)
As i am new to this i will be unable to configure it without step by step guidance 
Please help my by explaining.
I have tried installing tomcat6 but when i try to access the server at localhost:8080 it is unable to find one.

Comment: You can't use just Apache's httpd server.  You will need something like Tomcat to make that work.  There are lots of tutorials online for setting up Tomcat.

Comment: i tried many tutorials before asking here. many tutorials works until any of the mentioned step is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be that: http://www.puschitz.com/InstallingTomcat.html ? 
It's manual for Debian, but I think, it may be useful.

Comment: Tomcat6 in tutorial. I will try installing Tomcat7 hope that it does not have much change in the installation steps.

Comment: as i have tried other tutorials there is some parts of tomcat6 remains on system. so followed the tutorial, Installed the latest version on 6.